# Virtualbox as remote server

Tags: python, virtualbox

I have a python script that works great on my virtual machine with linux ubuntu(last edition), i have a shared hosting with my website (cheap one and python scripts run extremly slow).
I was wondering if can turn my virtual machine into a 'server' so i can make calls from my real server to my virtual machine and then handle the response. 
A simple example: let's say in my virtual machine i'have a python script that take `sys.argv[1]` that is a string and output its length, in my scenario i pass the string from my server, the virtual machine runs the script with the argument i've passed and then i can handle the respons back in my web server.
this is not a permanent solution i need this only for a couple of days.
Is this possible? is this simple? 
The most useful thing i've found is [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42480/how-to-turn-your-home-ubuntu-pc-into-a-lamp-web-server/)
Thanks in advance Nico.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to communicate between your VM and your hosted machine. For this you can use pretty much any programming language of your choice. Python might be pretty easy here. You have to learn about socket programming (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html))

However it could be difficult to use the VM on your local machine as the server because it would have to be reachable from the internet (which it is probably not because of the NAT in your router). This means that you have to find out, if your hoster allows opening sockets via python. If it does not allow this, you might have to take another approach to the problem. If it allows it, the python script running on your hosted machine has to be the server and the script on your VM has to be the client which registers at the server.

This might seem complicated but it is not, if you understand how sockets work. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that your VM is the client and the hosted machine is the server.

Comment: Thanks! and waht if i install openssh-server on my ubuntu client, then from my webserver with php command ssh2_exec i run the python script on VM?

Comment: Your openssh server will not be reachable from the internet (and therefore from your webserver) by default. To accomplish this, you need to forward a port in your router. There are many good tutorials out there showing how you can do that. Note that your external IP (the IP reachable from the internet) changes frequently. If you don't want to change it in your script on your webserver everytime, you might want to take a look at dyndns.